# How to get the close X button to work on popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

Everything of this code is working but the close button. I have been racking my brain over it for 2 hours and nothing. Can someone look into the code for me please.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#popup_this').bPopup(); });

<div id="popup_this" style="z-index: 9998">
<span class="button b-close">
    <span>X</span>
</span>

.b-close {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
background: #000;
padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 9000;}
```

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: $('#popup_this .button').click(function(){
     $('#popup_this').hide();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".b-close" ).click(function() {
      $( "#popup_this" ).hide( "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you!